# Using variables in jstl if statement

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have something like this

```
 <c:forEach var="authority" items="#{SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.authorities}">

      <c:if test="${fn:contains( ${authority} , ROLE_ADMIN) }">

      </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

but it does not working, any ide how can I make this? Maybe there is some other way?

//Edited

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

1. You should not nest EL expressions. Just reference the EL variable the usual way.

   ```
   <c:if test="${fn:contains(authority, ROLE_ADMIN)}">
   ```
2. It's not clear from the question context if `ROLE_ADMIN` is already in the EL scope. But you need to know that you cannot reference constants in EL. If it's for example an `enum`, then it's good to know that they are just evaluated as `String`. You need to quote it then.

   ```
   <c:if test="${fn:contains(authority, 'ROLE_ADMIN')}">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing ")" in your if test:

```
 <c:forEach var="authority" items="#{SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.authorities}">

      <c:if test="${fn:contains( {$authority} , ROLE_ADMIN ) }">

      </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is not a problem,a have just misstyped